# Creating a Database using DBExpress in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, firebird, dbexpress

I need to create a Firebird Database programmatically using DBExpress. I have done this for SQL server, by first connecting to Master, then passing in the script for Create to a query, but with Firebird I have a little chicken and egg problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a good tip from a collegue that created some code for the Freepascal project. It doesn't use DB express, but according to him it is the only way to create a database with code. This code is based on the InterBase manual, and uses a call from the gdslib / fbclient dll:

```
procedure TIBConnection.CreateDB;

var ASQLDatabaseHandle,
    ASQLTransactionHandle : pointer;
    CreateSQL : String;
    pagesize : String;
begin
  CheckDisConnected;
  {$IfDef LinkDynamically}
    InitialiseIBase60;
  {$EndIf}
  ASQLDatabaseHandle := nil;
  ASQLTransactionHandle := nil;
  CreateSQL := 'CREATE DATABASE ';
  if HostName <> '' then
    CreateSQL := CreateSQL + ''''+ HostName+':'+DatabaseName + ''''
  else
    CreateSQL := CreateSQL + '''' + DatabaseName + '''';

  if UserName <> '' then
    CreateSQL := CreateSQL + ' USER ''' + Username + '''';
  if Password <> '' then
    CreateSQL := CreateSQL + ' PASSWORD ''' + Password + '''';
  pagesize := params.Values['PAGE_SIZE'];
  if pagesize <> '' then
    CreateSQL := CreateSQL + ' PAGE_SIZE '+pagesize;

  if isc_dsql_execute_immediate(@FStatus[0],@ASQLDatabaseHandle,@ASQLTransactionHandle,length(CreateSQL),@CreateSQL[1],Dialect,nil) <> 0 then
    CheckError('CreateDB', FStatus);

  if isc_detach_database(@FStatus[0], @ASQLDatabaseHandle) <> 0 then
    CheckError('CreateDB', FStatus);

  {$IfDef LinkDynamically}
    ReleaseIBase60;
  {$EndIf}
end;
```

The trick is the isc_dsql_execute_immediate function. I hope this code helps you. Here are the links to the Freepascal source files where this code comes from:

[Unit containing CreateDB function](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/tags/release_2_2_2/packages/fcl-db/src/sqldb/interbase/ibconnection.pp?revision=11487&view=markup)

[Unit containing API call isc_dsql_execute_immediate](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/tags/release_2_2_2/packages/ibase/src/ibase60.inc?revision=11487&view=markup)

Comment: Installation directory of Firebird contains some model examples. Check following directory on your computer:
C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\examples\api
Method prototypes can be found in directory:
C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\include

Answer (score 1):

Run a script isql

isql-i createDB.sql

CreateDB.sql the file includes the command to create the database as shown below.

```
SET SQL DIALECT 3;
CREATE DATABASE 'C:\DATABASE\DB.FDB'
USER 'SYSDBA' PASSWORD 'masterkey'
PAGE_SIZE 4096
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET WIN1252;
QUIT;
```