# FreePascal clong data type to Delphi

Tags: delphi, types, freepascal, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to use the FreePascal 2.2.2 `ibase60.inc` from the bottom link of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423877/512728) in Delphi Tokyo.

It starts with the following definitions:

```
type
  {  Unsigned types }

  UChar                = Byte;
  UShort               = Word;
  UInt                 = DWord;
  ULong                = DWord;

  { Signed types }

  Int                  = LongInt;
  Long                 = LongInt;
  Short                = SmallInt;
  Float                = Single;

  { Pointers to basic types }

  PInt                 = ^Int;
  PShort               = ^Short;
  PUShort              = ^UShort;
  PLong                = ^Long;
  PULong               = ^ULong;
  PFloat               = ^Float;
  PUChar               = ^UChar;
  PVoid                = ^Pointer;

const
   ISC_TRUE = 1;
   ISC_FALSE = 0;
const
   ISC__TRUE = ISC_TRUE;
   ISC__FALSE = ISC_FALSE;

Type
   ISC_USHORT    = word;
   ISC_STATUS    = clong;
   ISC_INT64     = int64;
   ISC_UINT64    = UInt64; // qword;
   ISC_LONG      = Longint;

   PISC_USHORT = ^ISC_USHORT;
   PISC_STATUS = ^ISC_STATUS;
   PPISC_STATUS = ^PISC_STATUS;
   PISC_INT64 = ^ISC_INT64;
   PISC_UINT64 = ^ISC_UINT64;
   PISC_LONG = ^ISC_LONG;
```

How do I convert that `ISC_STATUS = clong` type to Delphi? It isn't in the [FreePascal Variables and Data Types](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Variables_and_Data_Types) and so far I have been unable to find working code.

Comment: Every attempt to Google it, a majority of the results are Google thinking I want "clone".

Comment: `clong` type (like other types derived from `C` language) basically declared in the [`ctypes` module](https://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/rtl/inc/ctypes.pp). for unix-based systems you need to walk through some includes ([`aliasctp.inc`](https://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/rtl/unix/aliasctp.inc) -> [`ctypes.inc`](https://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/rtl/unix/ctypes.inc)), for other OSes it is declared in the `ctypes.pp` as `clong = int64;` or `clong = longint;` depending on target CPU. In other words: use sources.

Comment: A C long maps to Delphi Longint. The earlier comments are just clutter.

Comment: @Abelisto Thanks for that pointer to ctypes.inc, I don't know much about FP. Can come in handy next time. One follow up question though. *That* file says qword=int64, where I translated qword= uint64, because [this](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/qword.html) says 64-bit unsigned 0..18446744073709551615

Comment: `QWORD` should be `UInt64`, but some old versions of Delphi only had signed `Int64`. Perhaps the same was true for fpc.

Comment: @JanDoggen It is in the `{$ifndef FPC}` section, probably for compatibility with old versions of Delphi as David mentioned.

Comment: This comment is in the ctypes.pp I have here: `qword = int64;  // Keep h2pas "uses ctypes" headers working with delphi.`. So this seems to be  related to how h2pas translated `QWORD` when Delphi only had signed Int64s, as @David says.