# FreePascal PACKRECORDS directive to Delphi

Tags: delphi, struct, record, freepascal, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to use the FreePascal 2.2.2 `ibase60.inc` from the bottom link of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423877/512728) in Delphi Tokyo (A 32-bit Windows VCL application).

It contains the directive `{$PACKRECORDS C}`. The [documentation](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu60.html) says:

> The special value C is used to specify alignment as by the GNU CC compiler. It should be used only when making import units for C routines.

Googling for [gnu cc struct alignment](https://www.google.com/search?q=gnu+cc+struct+alignment) I read e.g. in [The Lost Art of C Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) that on modern processors

> ... basic C types on x86 and ARM are self-aligned. Pointers, whether 32-bit (4-byte) or 64-bit (8-byte) are self-aligned too.

Is there anything I have to replace that code directive with to ensure proper (non-)packing in Delphi for calling those methods in the InterBase/Firebird DLLs? Or can I assume that Delphi behaves like GNU CC?

[Here](http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/tags/release_2_2_2/packages/ibase/src/ibase60.inc?revision=11487&view=markup) is the complete code for that `ibase60.inc` file.

Comment: I'd expect that you use default alignment and all will be good.

Comment: Delphi has the [`$ALIGN`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Align_fields_(Delphi)) directive.

Comment: Also perhaps need {$MINENUMSIZE 4}

Answer (score 0):

gcc alignment aka natural alignment aligns every fields on a boundary divisible by its size. If you click through on Ondrej's link to [this page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Record_Types) you'll see that every type is aligned to its size. (even though IMHO the language in the page that Ondrej links to is clumsy)

So if there are no 16-byte base types in play, it should be ok. (and I assume as soon as Delphi adapts 16-bytes base types, it will change A+ to mean A16+)

I know fpc has 16-byte alignment, but don't even know what the corresponding field types are (int128 on 64-bit powerpc? SSE types?)